# local Apache server looking in wrong folder for a file

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I installed an existing Wordpress site on my Ubuntu machine which is running Apache2.

Almost all of the web pages are loading properly  except for one custom section of the site, i.e. https://localhost.wordpress/app.  When I try to get to this page I get an error in my apache2 error log:

```
[Fri Jan 17 16:57:03 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/app, referer: http://localhost.wordpress/
```

The Apache server seems to be looking for the file in the wrong place.  Instead of going to where I have the wordpress site (`/home/dev/public_html/wordrpress/public`) it is looking in `/var/www/app`.

How can I change this?

I'm not too familiar with Wordpress, but the problem seems to be with this **app folder** which I'm not used to seeing in Wordpress installations.

### My Setup

Folder Structure:

[image]

I've configured a virtual host so that this site runs from the same folder location as the rest of my sites.  I.e. in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/wordrpress` I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName  localhost.wordrpress
  ServerAlias www.localhost.wordrpress

  DocumentRoot /home/dev/public_html/wordrpress/public

  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/dev/public_html/wordrpress/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/dev/public_html/wordrpress/log/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I also have made sure the site resolves locally to my computer by updting my `/etc/hosts` file to include:

```
# DNS for localhost wordpress site development.
127.0.0.1 localhost.wordpress
127.0.0.1 www.localhost.wordpress
```

I set up the **https configuration** by folloing these instructions & running these commands into my terminal:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl

sudo a2ensite default-ssl

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I also changed the wp_options table of the database to use my machines localhost url for the wordpress siteurl etc.

Comment: Old question, but it looks like apache is trying to find the file and failing. Look for default file locations in the normal apache config files, and look in apache's `sites_enabled` directory for other website config files create a global default value (e.g., `<VirtualHost _default_:*>` or else `DocumentRoot` commands not enclosed in `VirtualHost` markup.)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(app).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]
```

To your default WordPress installation htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

So it should look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(app).*$ [NC]
RewriteRule . - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought that might be it but I still get the same error: `[Sat Jan 18 15:23:02 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/app, referer: http://localhost.000-wordpress/`.  Maybe the rewrite rule should be slightly different as the app folder is in `/home/dev/public_html/000-wordpress/public/`?